# Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK IOS React Native not showing the Device ID in the Marketing Cloud All Contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, mobilepush-ios, react-native

MobilePush SDK IOS React Native not showing the Device ID in the Marketing Cloud All Contacts

Base on the links here: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

We have implemented all the things we have to do here but, the device id does not show up in the

All Contacts.

I have checked the information on the list below

1. App ID
2. App Access Token
3. Marketing Cloud URL

Thank you for the response in advance

Comment: What do the device logs say?  Are you developing a crossplatform application?  If so, are your Android devices registering?

Comment: Hello @BillMote thanks for your response, We are developing the cross-platform application, and my Android device already registered but we have an issue with the IOS site. Contact key that we have set up in the code show up in the All contacts in the Marketing cloud but there is no device id in that record. I will upload the device logs later

Comment: I have an update on this so we found the issues that we are implementing the more than 1 SDK at the same time. In the IOS site, base on the official document it's said that "Warning: If a push SDK uses method swizzling as a means of replacing iOS framework code at runtime, the MarketingCloudSDK may not work as expected."

Comment: If base what document said its looks like we have to set the Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK as the main SDK right because there is a phase in the link show that "Some SDKs offer a secondary implementation, which uses standard app delegate methods. If so, you must use the secondary implementation." @BillMote

Comment: Glad you sorted it out!!